# Grails- Add link href to button

Tags: grails

I'm building a simple Grails app for a web development class.  For the most part, the app is finished, but I'm having one sticking issue.

On the index page, I have a series of buttons that correspond to the `List`, `Create`, and other templates that are built in Grails via scaffolding.  How can I dynamically pass on the correct path to the controller action?

In order to do this, I need to get the current page URL and add the proper location.  Is that possible to do in Grails or should I stick with jquery or some other ajax solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve here,

If you want to generate link to controller actions that you can use for button href, you can do it like this,

```
<button href="${createLink(controller:'foo', action:'bar')}"/>
```

See the [createLink](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html) tag

If you want to know controller and action name, ${controllerName} and ${actionName} can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `${controllerName}` to get the name of the current controller?

An alternative might be `${params.controller}`, but again, not 100% sure it works in gsps